# Is there an ABAP interactive console?

Tags: debugging, console, abap, interactive

What I mean:

In many IDEs (I know Eclipse and Visual Studio better) there's a functionality called an interactive console.

This allows me that, in debugging mode, when I hit a breakpoint, or I take control of my code for whatever reason, I can execute code that is aware of the context of my application.

That means that I can modify the contents of variables BUT ALSO I can call methods of my objects. in Eclipse (for Java) i could even define new local variables and "do stuff" with them.

I think this would be extremely useful in such cases as when one needs to go through a very long process (in the interface) in order to test the code, and when at some point in code, testing different FuBa calls would help.

I am aware of how the contents of variables can be modified in the debugger at run time, and I agree this basically does the same thing I ask (although slower).

I am also aware that the new debugger (from version 7.02 i think) allows debugger scripts to run, which could generate code dynamically, but this is also too much hassle (although one could start from here in implementing a nice interactive console).

So is there such a tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, there is no such thing (and I'm tempted to say *thank $DEITY there's no such thing*).

Comment: Why do you consider the lack of a tool a good thing? as I see it, it could save a lot of time.

Comment: So does replacing values while debugging the system - and still, half of the time, we have to defend ourselves for using the tool. Besides, there's always some fast-fingered freddy who will call a method without knowing what it does or caring about the consequences. If you wreck your own PC, that's your problem. But this is a system with potentially thousands of developers working on it...

Comment: well then shouldn't we fire all the developers just in case they mess something up? any tool should be used responsibly, and good software is developed by good methodologies, not by people - just saying :P

Comment: @vlad-ardelean: I totally agree, and as we all know, there are **only** competent, responsible, friendly and extremely well qualified developers out there.

Comment: well are all those who program in eclipse, visual studio (and other IDEs) more competent and responsible than those who code in SE80? :)

Comment: Nope, they just have their own systems to tear apart.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is such a thing that allows you to do this in ABAP.

What I do find useful is that you can completely jump sections of code backwards or forwards to miss out lines or execute lines again. This basically allows you to create your own flow during the debugging session.

You can access this by placing the cursor on the line you want to jump to and select

> File->Goto Statement

or press Shift+F12.

You could add in un-reachable code (inside and if (0!=0)?) and skip to this at debug time to set your variables up (and remove once you are finished). Agree it is a bit more work but it is very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

In ABAP debug you can stop the program flow (breakpoint) at breakpoint sentence, when a variable change or be equal to certain value (watchpoint), you can skip a routine or method or any other structured or grouped code, skip from actual syructured block code to the next sentence of calling, you can view the call's stack change values of variables or alter data of tables, insert, change, modify a line. Even you can put an extern breakpoint, it means, breakpoint from an extern calling, for example java calling sap, it stopping when sap starts.

Comment: I was aware of that. Thank you for the clarrification. Some people might find this useful.